# different static images for ios app - for launch and for "applicationdidenterforeground"

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, background-image

Based on what I understand at least 1 "Default.png" image is required for all ios apps to be used as the Launch image when the app is loading.

However, I have a situation where when the app 1st launches it has a login screen which looks completely different than a menu-screen which is used in all the post-login phases of the app.

Im looking to see if there is a way to supply 1 default.png image to be used if the app is in "not logged in state" and another image when the app is in "logged in state". The state would be set when the app goes into the background. So when it comes back to the foreground the correct background is used.

Is anything like this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the launch image beyond localization.

If you have a navigation bar or anything that's constant between the two views, you could show just that in your launch image. If not, a logo might be a better user experience.

There are many cases where you will decide not to use a launch image that appears like the actual UI (it's intended purpose), and this may be one of them.

On one of my apps, the first view has buttons with text on it. If I included a launch image for each localization (for each device and orientation), my bundle would have grown quite large, and beyond the 50MB limit for cellular download.

Also, it seemed odd behavior to have buttons on a launch image that would do nothing if pressed until the app finished loading.

Therefore, I decided to forgo the traditional use of the launch image and put my company name in a sort of splash screen on it instead.

My app is in the app store, so Apple is fine with these kinds of choices.

I could have created launch images with blank, disabled buttons, or with no buttons at all, but again, it just seemed odd to me. Even a launch image used as a splash screen gives the effect to the user that your app launched immediately.